# Regex Crafting SMART data

Tags: regex, perl

I'm racking my brain trying to come up with a regex that will be able to pull the data I want in this SMART data output:

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  139) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 100) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.
```

The regex I've come up with so far is:

```
/([^A-Za-z]?:)([\w\s\/().\-]+\.)/gm
```

The objective of my regex is to get the "Values" of each "General SMART Values" from `smartctl -a` output. The problem is that the output is formatted in a particular way that's making it difficult for me to pull the values I want into an array.

I'm able to pull just the SMART Values Keys such as `Offline data collection status`, or `Self-test execution status`, so now I'm working on pull the values of each of those parameters. Which would be something like `(139) seconds` or `(0x00) Offline data collection activity was never started.`

What separates the key from value is this colon followed by some white spaces. However in one of the values it contains text that also has a colon in it which is making the capturing extremely difficult. I need to capture all of the following without accidentally capturing the next parameter values.

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  139) seconds.
```

So from the above I need to capture just the following.

```
(0x00)  Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
```

Without going in and capturing `Self-test execution status:` as part of it as that is the next parameter key.

Any help of thoughts to this situation would be helpful.

Comment: FYI, you're using Python regex in your regex.com expression. I don't think it makes a difference in this case, but Python regex != Perl regex.

Comment: I know it's python regex on that site, I didn't see an option for Perl, but as you stated probably not a big difference here as the regex expression should be universal. If you have a website that will do the same thing but display for Perl regex, please let me know.

Comment: @HuyNguyen I would use PCRE for Perl

Comment: PCRE would be closer, although they're still not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I think we're losing focus of my problem. I was merely using the regex101 as a visually easier way of describing the issue I'm having and looking for advice in terms of regex expression crafting as i'm not amazing at it. Any and all suggestions provided I can test against a perl script that I'm running to pull the data I'm looking for, I just figure breaking out the regex portion to be displayed was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could leverage on the fact that the keys start at the beginning
of line and the value's always have at least a horizontal whitespace
before each one.

`(?m)((?:^(?!\s)[^:\n]*\n?)+):(\h+.*?(?:\n|\z)(?:^\h+.*?(?:\n|\z))*)?`

Don't need modifiers it's included.

```
while ( $smartdata =~ /(?m)((?:^(?!\s)[^:\n]*\n?)+):(\h+.*?(?:\n|\z)(?:^\h+.*?(?:\n|\z))*)?/g )
{
    push @key, $1;
    push @value, $2;
}
```

Expanded

```
 (?m)
 (                             # (1 start), Key
      (?:
           ^ 
           (?! \s )
           [^:\n]* 
           \n? 
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 : 
 (                             # (2 start), Value
      \h+ .*?  
      (?: \n | \z )
      (?:
           ^ \h+ .*?  
           (?: \n | \z )
      )*
 )?                            # (2 end)
```

Perl sample

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;

my $smartdata = <DATA>;

my @key = ();
my @val = ();

while ( $smartdata =~ /(?m)((?:^(?!\s)[^:\n]*\n?)+):(\h+.*?(?:\n|\z)(?:^\h+.*?(?:\n|\z))*)?/g )
{
    push @key, $1;
    if (defined $2 ) {
        push @val, $2;
    }
    else {
        push @val, '';
    }
}

for ( 0 .. ($#key-1) )
{
     print "key $_ = $key[$_]\n";
     print "value = $val[$_]\n-------------------\n";
}

__DATA__

Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  139) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.



Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 100) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.
```

Output

```
key 0 = Offline data collection status
value =   (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.

-------------------
key 1 = Self-test execution status
value =       (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.

-------------------
key 2 = Total time to complete Offline
data collection
value =         (  139) seconds.

-------------------
key 3 = Offline data collection
capabilities
value =             (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.

-------------------
key 4 = SMART capabilities
value =             (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.

-------------------
key 5 = Error logging capability
value =         (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.

-------------------
key 6 = Short self-test routine
recommended polling time
value =     (   2) minutes.

-------------------
key 7 = Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time
value =     ( 100) minutes.

-------------------
key 8 = Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time
value =     (   3) minutes.

-------------------
```

Comment: This works for me, there are a few keys that contain the words "recommended polling time"

I plugged it into my script and it's pulling results beautifully.

Comment: Seems to work, I included a sample. The regex will allow the colon in the body of a value, it's not a problem.

Comment: Running it on the entire data text, instead of line by line, works fine.

Comment: Your example output appears to be missing one result due to using `$#key-1` instead of imply `$#key` in your printing loop.

Answer (score 1):

Both keys and data are split across lines so we have to handle both cases:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

my $lastkey;

my $prefixkey = "";

while (my $smartdata = <DATA>) {
    chomp $smartdata;

    if ($smartdata =~ m/^\S/) {
        if ($smartdata =~ m/^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$/) { # is a complete or end of a key and data

            $lastkey = $prefixkey ? "$prefixkey $1" : $1;

            $data{$lastkey} = $2;

            $prefixkey = "";
        }
        else { # this is the start of a key
            $smartdata =~ s/(^\s+|\s+$)//; # strip whitespace
            $prefixkey = $smartdata;
        }
    }   
    else { # this is a data continuation
        $smartdata =~ s/(^\s+|\s+$)//; # strip whitespace
        $data{$lastkey} .= " $smartdata";
    }
}

for my $key (keys(%data)) {
    print("$key:\t$data{$key}\n");
}

__DATA__
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  139) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 100) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.
```

Produces:

```
Error logging capability:   (0x01) Error logging supported. General Purpose Logging supported.
Total time to complete Offline data collection: (  139) seconds.
SCT capabilities:   (0x1081) SCT Status supported.
Offline data collection capabilities:   (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate. Auto Offline data collection on/off support. Suspend Offline collection upon new command. No Offline surface scan supported. Self-test supported. Conveyance Self-test supported. Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities: (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering power-saving mode. Supports SMART auto save timer.
Conveyance self-test routine recommended polling time:  (   3) minutes.
Self-test execution status: (   0) The previous self-test routine completed without error or no self-test has ever  been run.
Extended self-test routine recommended polling time:    ( 100) minutes.
Offline data collection status: (0x00) Offline data collection activity was never started. Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Short self-test routine recommended polling time:   (   2) minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of this data isn't the greatest, but at least it's predictable. We can parse it according to what the beginning of each line looks like.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %data;
my $key;
my $record;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    if (s/^\s+/ /g) {
        $record .= $_;
    } elsif (s/^([^:]+):\s\s+//) {
        if (length($record)) {
            $data{$key} = $record;
            $key = '';
        }

        $key .= $1;
        $record = $_;
    } else {
        $data{$key} = $record;
        $key = $_ . ' ';
        $record = '';
    }
}

$data{$key} = $record;
print Dumper(\%data);

__DATA__
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (  139) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 100) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Error logging capability' => '(0x01) Error logging supported. General Purpose Logging supported.',
          'Total time to complete Offline data collection' => '(  139) seconds.',
          'SCT capabilities' => '(0x1081) SCT Status supported.',
          'Offline data collection capabilities' => '(0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate. Auto Offline data collection on/off support. Suspend Offline collection upon new command. No Offline surface scan supported. Self-test supported. Conveyance Self-test supported. Selective Self-test supported.',
          'SMART capabilities' => '(0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering power-saving mode. Supports SMART auto save timer.',
          'Conveyance self-test routine recommended polling time' => '(   3) minutes.',
          'Self-test execution status' => '(   0) The previous self-test routine completed without error or no self-test has ever been run.',
          'Extended self-test routine recommended polling time' => '( 100) minutes.',
          'Offline data collection status' => '(0x00) Offline data collection activity was never started. Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.',
          'Short self-test routine recommended polling time' => '(   2) minutes.'
        };
```